# In which anime characters fight using top-toy like objects?

Tags: beyblade

The anime is more or less like [Pokemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_%28anime%29). Except in matches instead of Pokemon, the characters use objects that look like [top-toys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top) and while the top-toy-like object spins, spirit-like creatures come out of it, Which anime is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about beyblade.

From [Wikipdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyblade):

> Beyblade, known in Japan as Explosive Shoot Beyblade (爆転シュートベイブレード Bakuten Shūto Beiburēdo?), is a Japanese manga series written and illustrated by Takao Aoki in order to promote sales of **spinning tops** called "Beyblades"

(emphasis mine)

Here is a picture of one of the main characters holding a beyblade (taken from [fanpop](http://www.fanpop.com/clubs/beyblade/images/23517778/title/tyson-granger-photo)):

[image]